# Google OAuth2 response_type is missing

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to redirect users to the Google OAuth login page to so we can get access to an access token. However, upon redirection, I'm hit with the following error:

`Required parameter is missing: response_type`

It's clear that the response type parameter is preset and correctly setup. I even checked the network request sent by the initial page load and response_type is present.

Here's the exact URL I'm redirecting to:

```
window.location.replace(
    `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
    response_type=token&
    scope=${encodeURIComponent("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords")}&
    access_type=${encodeURIComponent("offline")}&
    include_granted_scopes=true&
    redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(`${window.location.origin}/dashboard/link`)}&
    client_id=${encodeURIComponent("some-client-id")}&
    prompt=select_account`
)
```

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow) guide for implementation

Comment: The problem is caused by an incorrectly generated URI. Edit your post and show the actual URI generated by your code. My guess is that `encodeURIComponent` is over encoding the URI.